# Creating Database. Why is it not working?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a problem. I want to make a Books database with C# with serialNumber, Author, Name and Year of publishing columns. I did the code and I don't have any errors but when i start it the console is left black and it doesn't do anything. Can someone tell me why it´s not working?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace T4DB1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=master; Integrated Security = True");
            {
                string create = "if not exists (select * from sys.databases where name='Buecher') create database [Buecher] else begin drop database [Buecher] create database [Buecher] end ";
                SqlCommand createDB = new SqlCommand(create, conn);
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    createDB.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine("Database created");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error");
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
                conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog=Buecher; Integrated Security = True");
                create = " create table Buecher1 ( ISBNNummer varchar(10) not null Primary Key, Autor varchar(40), Titel varchar(50), Erscheinungsjahr smallint)";
                createDB = new SqlCommand(create, conn);
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    createDB.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine("Table created");
                    string insertrow = "insert into Buecher1 (ISBNNummer, Autor, Titel, Erscheinungsjahr) values('2658A42', 'Douglas Adams', 'Galaxy', 2007)";
                    createDB = new SqlCommand(insertrow, conn);
                    createDB.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    string insertrow2 = "insert into Buecher1 (ISBNNummer, Autor, Titel, Erscheinungsjahr) values('58624FG85', 'Charles Dickens', 'White Fang',1992)";
                    createDB = new SqlCommand(insertrow2, conn);
                    createDB.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    string insertrow3 = "insert into Buecher1 (ISBNNummer, Autor, Titel, Erscheinungsjahr) values('65224AS4', 'Erik Corr', 'Somewhere', 2014)";
                    createDB = new SqlCommand(insertrow3, conn);
                    createDB.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    string select = "Select * From Buecher1";
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(select, conn);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); da.Fill(dt);
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ISBNNummer: " + row["ISBNNummer"] + " " + "Autor: " + row["Autor"] + " " + "Titel: " + row["Titel"] + " " + "Erscheinungsjahr:" + row["Erscheinungsjahr"]);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the first line of your Main function, and step through it to see where it either breaks or stalls.

Comment: It would make a lot more sense to use SQL Server Data Tools for this.

Comment: What about generate script? do you know about it?

Comment: What do you mean to set a breakpoint on the first line? I know it would be easier with SQL Data Tools but i have to do it this way. Thanks

Comment: Generate script? No im not familiar with it. I dont understand if it creates the datebase or not. I don´t  get any errors but also i dont get anything just the black screen.

Comment: Perhaps server is not reachable and you have a very long timeout. as someone mentioned before, set breakpoints and step through to see where the code hangs

Comment: If you run this application ti is impossible that the console remains empty. At least `Database created` or `Error` must be printed on the console depending on your code.

Comment: What I mean by 'set a breakpoint' is right click on the first line of your Main function (SQLConnection con = ...), click Breakpoint - Insert Breakpoint. Now you can debug your program and step through it line by line to see exactly what is happening.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, use F9 key to set a breakpoint on catch block. When you run the application, if there is any error the application will break on the catch block. Look at the "Message" property of the ex object. That will give you an idea of why the database is not  getting created, if at all there is any error.

Comment: Well that´s the problem even if i use just the first tr-catch-finally block without any more code it should say/write "Database Created" or "Error" nut it doesnt do anything , it just remains black.

Comment: Thanks people, i found it. There was nothing wrong with the code. Sql services in Computer Services panel were on "Manual" and they didnt run. When i changed that it works. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You should learn from this experience and add code to your app that echoes 'connecting to database....' so you at least have a clue whats going on.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are using SQL Server.  Just consider this statement:

```
if not exists (select * from sys.databases where name='Buecher')
    create database [Buecher]
```

It does not behave as you expect.  The command is first compiled.  During this phase, if `Buecher` exists, you'll get an error on `create database [Buecher]'` because you cannot create a database that already exists.  You might protest, "But that is why I have the `if`!"  Too bad. the compiler is not listening.  You see the `if` isn't executed until the execution phase -- after the compile phase.

And, the same is true of the `drop`.

A typical way to handle this is to use dynamic SQL.  That postpones the compilation until the execution.  So, this snipper should work:

```
if not exists (select * from sys.databases where name='Buecher')
    exec('create database [Buecher] ');
```

Comment: Why not reverse the condition? Always testing for EXIST and delete if true, then create. Should avoid the problem right?

Comment: Sure, it works right now as i´ve turned on the sql services in control panel

Comment: @Steve . . . If you reverse the condition, the `drop` will fail.

Comment: I mean: `IF EXISTS (select * from sys.databases .....)) DROP DATABASE [Buecher];` This is exactly how the generate script DROP/CREATE for database works in SSMS